# How to create another page

Tags: html, roblox

I am trying to make a website dashboard that would connect to a ROBLOX script. I am trying to make the ROBLOX script add a div and some info to the website. I have seen Forum pages i.e https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/forums
In forums, you can make your own forum page and it posts that website page. Is it possible for a ROBLOX script to do that? If not, how would I make another page on the website create the page? I currently have tried about 3 things and they all failed miserably.Thanks! Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to add pages to a website, your going to need to learn some webcode like PHP. It is impossible to create this with a ROBLOX script because you will need to connect to a web database like SQL. Here are some links you you can learn more:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp

Comment: Alright! Thanks, I will have to mark your answer as right in 7 minutes. :/

Comment: No problem. There are also services online which can generate a form for you, so you may want to check out those.